# How to fix sepolicy denials?

Tags: android, selinux, device-tree

How to fix a sepolicy denial in the .te files ?

Like this one : `[ 08-06 18:30:27.029  2267: 2267 I/main     ]
type=1400 audit(0.0:219): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker" dev="debugfs" ino=447 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For that, you should add the following to zygote.te:

```
allow zygote debugfs:file { getattr };
```

A good guide to learn how to fix SEPolicy denials is https://msfjarvis.dev/posts/understanding-and-resolving-selinux-denials-on-android/

External edit: Both syntax are fine; with/without the curly braces. The braces are simply to allow more attributes to a policy effectively, all in one line.
For example purposes:

```
allow zygote debugfs:file { getattr read };
```

Instead of:

```
allow zygote debugfs:file getattr;
allow zygote debugfs:file read;
```

Comment: Gist link in broken.

Answer (score 1):

Use audit2allow tool

Whenever you get denial message, save them to some log file

if you want to search for specific task, try to grep its name while dumping related messages

```
dmesg | grep avc | grep some_task_name > log.txt
```

and then use audit2allow tool to get information

```
audit2allow < log.txt
```

the audit2allow result of your log

```
#============= zygote ==============
allow zygote debugfs:file getattr;
```

which means you should add the allow rule to **zygote.te**

Also you can refer to guide [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement)